# Passing hidden value in angular

Tags: angularjs, hidden-field, ng-init, angularjs-ng-value

View:

```
  <ul ng-repeat="x in posts.post">
      {{x.name}}  {{x._id}} {{x.post}} {{x.user_id}} 
      <br>
      <ul ng-repeat="y in x.comment">
        {{y.comment}}
      </ul>
      <input type="text" style="display: none;" ng-model='new_comment.userId' value={{users2.id}} name="userId"  >
      <input type="text" style="display: none;" ng-model='new_comment.name' value={{users2.name}} name="userName"   >
      <textarea ng-model='new_comment.comment' name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
      </textarea> 
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Post Comment!" ng-click="addComment(x._id, new_comment)">
  </ul>
```

Controller:

```
UserFactory.getUser(function (data) {
    $scope.users2 = data;
});
```

Factory:

```
factory.getUser = function(callback) {
    $http.get("/user").success(function(output) {
        users2 = output;
        callback(users2);
    });
};
```

I am trying to pass the hidden values of users2.id and users2.name from the controller/factory into a form. I tried ng-init, ng-value as well as input type="hidden", but none works.

***So this is what I did to get it working***:

View:

```
  <form>

  <textarea ng-model='new_comment.comment' name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
  </textarea> 

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Post Comment!" ng-click="addComment(x._id, new_comment, users2.name, users2._id)">
  </form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addComment = function(id, comment, userName, userId) {

var commentValue = comment.comment;

var newComment = {comment: commentValue, name: userName, userId: userId};

postFactory.addComment(id, newComment, function () {

    postFactory.getComment(function (data) {
        $scope.comments = data;
    });

    $scope.new_comment = {};
});
};
```

Comment: $scope.users2 is working at the moment. When I console.log(data) in the controller it shows. The problem is making the data available in the form and pass it back to controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <input type="hidden" ng-model='new_comment.userId' value="{{users2.id}}" name="userId"  >
```

And while you are changing things

```
UserFactory.getUser
.then(function (data) {
    $scope.users2 = data;
});
```

with

```
factory.getUser = function() {
    return $http.get("/user");
};
```

as $http returns a promise

Answer (score 1):

Two way binding wouldn't work with `hidden` element, so I'd use `ng-value` to set the value of `type="hidden"` element

```
<input type="hidden" ng-value='new_comment.userId' name="userId"/>
<input type="hidden" ng-value='new_comment.name' name="userName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, return the promise.

```
factory.getUser = function(callback) {
    return $http.get("/user")
};
```

Controller:

```
UserFactory.getUser().success(function(output) {
    $scope.users2 = output.data;
});
```